# Android - How to use a local broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use  a local broadcast receiver.

In order to do so I"ve done the next steps -

1) At an Activity, where Iwould like something to happen, I've created a class -

```
private class NewGroupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("The group ", "GOT IN THE RECIVING");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

}
```

2) At the same activity I've used the next code in order to create a receiver -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NewGroupReceiver receiver = new NewGroupReceiver();

    //the intent filter will be action = "com.example.demo_service.action.SERVICE_FINISHED"
    IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("com.example.apps.action.NEW_GROUP");

    // register the receiver:
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

3) At the a service class I've used the next code to know when something has happened-

```
Intent resultsIntent=new Intent("com.example.apps.action.NEW_GROUP");

LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(resultsIntent);
```

Now the problem is that when the thing I WOuld like to know has happen - I see the it's get into the code that I've used at step 3, but it doesen't seem to get into the BroadcastReceiver - the step 1 code.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Since you are in an activity, try sending a broadcast via the context; this.sendBroadcast(resultIntent);

Comment: the code at step 3 is at a 'Service' class

Comment: should still work that way in a service

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Answer (score 14):

You are using the `LocalBroadcastManager` to send the request, but you register the receiver on the "global" Intent. You should either use LocalBroadcastManager to register the receiver or send the broadcast on the
application context:

**Step 2**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver (receiver, filter);
```

Comment: Can you reference documentation confirming that this is true? I.e. that a broadcast sent via the LocalBroadcastManager will not be received by a BroadcastReceiver that was registered via `Context.registerReceiver()`, even though that BroadcastReceiver is in the same app? I've been looking for confirmation of this but the docs don't really seem to say.

Comment: @LarsH unfortunately not, but that was the case from my experience back then in 2014