# Adding listner for a service

Tags: android, interface

I was wondering if there is a way to have a listener for a Service.In my scenario I have a Service class S that is initiated by a class A . Service class S has a method S().I want to have a callback to class A when the method s() is done executing .Is it possible in any way .Any link or reference or even a code snipet will be realy appreciated.

Comment: read about bound services

Comment: You can use messenger. Search for messenger + handler combination.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Localbroadcastreceiver to notify the activity when method S() finished execution.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347872/android-how-to-use-a-local-broadcast-receiver) question for details about how to use a Localbroadcastreceiver

There is no such thing as listener for a service.

Comment: I have thought about this.But,in my case I cant use a Localbroadcastreceiver

Comment: May I ask why you can't use it?

Comment: What about a Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging like in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging?rq=1

Comment: Am starting the service to detect a call from a particular number,for that I created a lib.So am not using any activity etc.Correct me if am wrong

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you here, I don't have experience with libraries in Android yet. Maybe see if the binding/unbinding to a service and the messaging mechanism from the second link might help you.